# Smallest prime of the form $68^k+k!+1$?

Tags: functions, prime-numbers, factorial

Let $f(n)$ be the smallest integer $k\ge 1$ such that $$n^k+k!+1$$ is prime or undefined if no such $k$ exists.

I determined the values $f(n)$ for the even numbers $2,4,6,\cdots $ and $f(56)$ turned out to be $2138$ giving the huge prime $$56^{2138}+2138!+1$$ with $6194$ digits found by the PFGW-program (a software checking large numbers for primality).

The first even $n$ for which I do not know whether $f(n)$ is defined is $n=68$

> Is there a prime of the form $68^k+k!+1$ with integer $k\ge 1$ ? If such a $k$ exists , it must be greater than $24\ 000$.

Comment: By definition $ f (n) $ is a prime,  so it can't be $2138 $. Also... where does this question come from?

Comment: Assuming you meant $f(n)$ being the $k$ that gives this prime, I'm still wondering how did you do the primality tests? $2138!$ is a huge number...

Comment: Yes, probably $ f (n) $ is the smallest $ k $ such that... Is it clear that $ f $ is increasing?

Comment: The only $k$ where $f(68)$ does not have a small factor are of the form $k=p \cdot 2^m$.

Comment: $n=98$ is the only other $n<100$ that does not have a result for $k<10000$.

Comment: After $68$ , the next numbers having no small solution are $98,104,128,148,168,214,224,258,278,294,296,314,320$ . I have found out $$f(278)=1364$$ $$f(294)=412$$ $$f(314)=2792$$